# rChart+nvd3 not showing up - Error: need finite ylim value

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I am able to plot my graphs successfully in `renderPlot` and in `ggplot`, but using `nPlot` for `rCharts`, I am receiving an error code:

```
Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
```

I only included the code that I know is troublesome:
My ui.R:

```
mainPanel(
     showOutput("plot3", "nvd3")
    ))
```

My server.R

```
  output$plot3 <- renderChart({
    candySelect<- input$candy
    d <- candyData[candyData$candy== candySelect, ]
    p3 <- nPlot(freq~purchase_month,  data = d ,group = "candy", type = "lineChart")
    p3$addParams(dom = 'plot3')
    p3
  })
```

Note: the `freq` and `purchase_month` are columns in my dataset.  `purchase_month` is in the format of, for example, "2014/04".

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: check your `input$` values for null please

Comment: Could I do: `d[!is.na(d)]`?

Comment: You should check `is.null(input$candy)` as default they are set to `NULL`

Comment: Okay, and should I remove them `is.null` returns `TRUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't formatted your dates, you can format your dates using something like `dates <- as.Date(dates, "%Y-%M")`.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

# sample Data
dat <- data.frame(
  purchase_month  = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12), 
  candy = sample(c(rep("Mars",4),rep("Bounty",4),rep("Twix",4))), 
  freq =round(runif(12)*500,0))

#format dates if needs be (they have to be a datetime object)
#dates <- as.Date(dates, "%Y-%M")

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Candy Select"), 
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput("candy", "Choose a candy:", choices = c("Mars", "Bounty","Twix"))),
                mainPanel(showOutput("plot3","Nvd3"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot3 <- renderChart2({
    dat <- dat[dat$candy %in% input$candy,]
    n <- nPlot(freq~purchase_month , group =  'candy', data = dat, type = 'lineChart')

    n$xAxis(tickFormat =   "#!
      function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y/%m')(new Date(d*1000*3600*24));} !#",rotateLabels = -90 )
    n
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**The plot shows the frequencies**

[image]